# If Ax = b is solvable then also..

Tags: matrices

I got this algebra homework I can't seem to do on my own.. I have this task where I have to prove something:

---

$A$ is a $m\times n$ matrix
and $b$ an element of $\mathbb R^m$
Now I shall show that if $Ax = b$ is solvable $A^TAX = A^TB$ is also solvable.

Furthermore I shall show that $Ax = b$ and $A^TAX = A^TB$ have the same solution if they are solvable

Transpose = T

---

My own ideas:

The first implication: If $Ax = b$ is solvable -> $A^TAx = A^Tb$ is solvable
I was thinking of doing this thing to the second equation:

A^TAx = A^Tb

is the same like

$A^TAx - A^Tb = 0$

$A^T ( Ax - b ) = 0$
etc

---

For the second proof that $Ax = b$ and $A^TAx = A^Tb$ have the same solution I wanna do something like this:

$A^T * y = (A^T * b)$

Or:

$A^TAx = A^Tb$
$(A^T)^{-1} A^TAx = A^T^{-1} A^Tb$ // Multiplication with the inverse element of the transpose
$I Ax = I b$
$Ax = b$

And this is the same solution like the other thing

Or

$Ax = b
$A^TAX = A^Tb$

How illegal is this from a scale of 1 - 10 ?

---

If possible I would like you to give me some hints or maybe a solution since I'm kinda ill at the moment but still have to ddo my homework somehow and missed out some lessons..
I'm better in calculating stuff but it's super hard for me to prove something in math so far..

Thank you very much for reading this and I hope you can help me
(English is not my first language so I'm sorry if there are any grammar mistakes)

---

Now that I think about it
I can't use the inverse since the requirements aren't needed.. so any other solution ?
The below with multiplicating the A^T could be true

Comment: What do you mean when you say "solvable"? Does it mean that there is a *unique* solution, or possibly an infinite solutions?

Comment: The task didn't specify this.. It just said solvable

Answer (score 3):

When you say "solvable", I assume you mean that there exists a *unique* solution, i.e. the inverse matrix exists. The following does not apply if "solvable" means that there can be multiple solutions.

Let's prove that $Ax = b$ is solvable if and only if $A^TAx=A^Tb$ is solvable, and their solutions are equal.

Assume (for $\implies$) that $Ax=b$ is solvable, then $A^{-1}$ exists and the solution is $x=A^{-1}b$. First note that if a matrix is invertible, so is its transpose, and [$(A^T)^{-1}=(A^{-1})^T$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Other_properties). We then have by multipling on left sides by $(A^T)^{-1}$ that
\begin{align}
A^TAx&=A^Tb\\
\underbrace{(A^T)^{-1}A^T}_{I}Ax &=\underbrace{(A^T)^{-1}A^T}_{I}b\\
Ax&=b
\end{align}
which was solvable by assumption with solution $x=A^{-1}b$. Hence $Ax=b$ solvable implies $A^TAx=A^Tb$ solvable with solution $x=A^{-1}b$.

Assume now (for $\impliedby$) that $A^TAx=A^Tb$ is solvable, then $(A^TA)^{-1}$ exists (and remember that $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$). The solution is given by $x=(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb = A^{-1}(A^T)^{-1}A^Tb = A^{-1}b$, which is simply the solution of $Ax=b$. Hence $A^TAx=A^Tb$ solvable implies $Ax=b$ solvable.

It is now shown that $Ax = b$ is solvable if and only if $A^TAx=A^Tb$ is solvable with solution $x=A^{-1}b$.

Comment: And thank you so much